# Acceder a la información de una imagen con $_FILES

Tags: php

Buenas,

Necesito acceder al tamaño en dimensiones de la imagen que se está subiendo con un input de tipo file, pero no veo más que la siguiente información al usar `var_dump($_FILES)`:

```
array(1) {
  ["thumb"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "image-8.jpeg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(45) "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpNWf8Zv"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(123369)
  }
}
```

Quería limitar a que las imágenes no superen ciertas dimensiones (como 90x90 pixeles) o el peso (80kb por ejemplo).

Comment: Tienes el tamaño a tus ojos: `["size"]=> int(123369)`. ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: Puedes limitarlo por el `size`.

Comment: Creo que antes de subirla al servidor no lo puedes determinar. Me parece que `getImageSize()` funciona solamente para imágenes ya presentes en el servidor. ¿Quizá con algún truco de jQuery o Javascript será posible?

Comment: Lo que comenta @A.Cedano, es cierto, aunque yo te recomiendo siempre validar las entradas en tu `BE`, es decir, nunca confiar en lo que se recibe es _"correcto"_ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `peso` de la imagen se encuentra en `$_FILES['thumb']['size']` y esta en `bytes`.

Con respecto a las dimensiones (`eg: ancho y alto`), puedes obtenerlas usando la función [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.getimagesize.php).

Ejemplo:

```
$image = $_FILES['thumb']['tmp_name'];
$peso = $_FILES['thumb']['size'] / 1024; // Bytes to Kilobytes
list($ancho, $alto, $tipo, $atributos) = getimagesize($image);

if ($ancho > 90 || $alto > 90) {
   // ERROR dimensiones!
} else if ($peso > 80) {
   // ERROR peso!
}
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! El único "pero" es que los condiciones hay que separarlos porque los errores son individuales y podrían presentarse los dos al mismo tiempo.

Comment: @JetLagFox, es un ejemplo. Tu puedes adaptarlo a gusto.

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo con **HTML5 y [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/)**

```js
window.URL    = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var miNavegador  = document.getElementById("navegador"),
    miVista = document.getElementById("vista"),
    useBlob   = false && window.URL; // setear a `true` para usar Blob en vez de Data-URL

function readImage (file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var image  = new Image();
    
    image.addEventListener("load", function () {
      var imageInfo = file.name +' '+
          image.width +'×'+
          image.height +' '+
          file.type +' '+
          Math.round(file.size/1024) +'KB';

      // Show image and info
      miVista.appendChild( this );
      miVista.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", imageInfo +'<br>');

      if (useBlob) {
        // Liberar memoria
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(image.src);
      }
    });
    image.src = useBlob ? window.URL.createObjectURL(file) : reader.result;
  });

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);  
}


miNavegador.addEventListener("change", function() {

  var files = this.files, errors = "";

  if (!files) {
    errors += "Subida de archivos no soportada por el navegador.";
  }

  if (files && files[0]) {

    for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];
      
      if ( (/\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif)$/i).test(file.name) ) {
        readImage( file ); 
      } else {
        errors += file.name +" Extensión de archivo no soportada\n";  
      }
      
    }
  }

  // Handle errors
  if (errors) {
    alert(errors); 
  }

});
```

```css
#vista img{height:150px;}
```

```html
<input id="navegador" type="file"  multiple />
<div id="vista"></div>
```